# Download files from an IP camera over telnet

Tags: file, curl, download, wget, telnet

so I just randomly scanned my ip camera with nmap. It turned out that the telnet port is open. And then I tried to access the telnet via telnet  . I typed in the loginname with 'root' and suddenly I can see what's inside the camera, plenty of directories and files.

My question is: I would like to download all the files and directories.

How can I do that?

I've tried curl and wget, and I didn't get anything except:

```
GET /backup/init.sh HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.20.3 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding/ identity
Host: 192.168.188.xx:23
Connection: Keep-Alive

(none) login:
```

So.....how can I correctly download the files and directories?

Comment: edit your Q to include the exact steps and commands you issued. Did you try including a path or directory as the target for `wget`, `curl`? Good luck.

Comment: As you have access to the machine why do not try to run (or install and run) ftp, ssh, http server and download the information you want.

Comment: @shellter. I tried including a path and many other paths to directories as the target. The example above was just an example. I tried downloading some single files and a bunch of single directories. Nothing worked.

Comment: @RomeoNinov excellent idea, I will try it definitely. I'll get back to you